# Local Image Upload with TinyMCE and VisualForce page

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm working with tinyMCE editor and I was wondering how to enable local image uploading? I'm using this editor inside of VisualForce page and iframe.

I tried all examples provided in documentation but none of them work for me...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.